# Delete multiple directories with a single batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I would like to make a batch script that can delete multiple directories at once. I've searched the web, but only seem to find methods for deleting multiple sub-directories or files. So far I can make a script to delete one specific folder using this structure:

```
rmdir "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies" /S /Q
```

I then tried a multitude of methods to declare other folders in different combinations and sequences but none seem to work. First I tried putting all other directories in a single line followed by /S /Q, then placing rmdir and  /S /Q at the start and end of each new path, then putting each path on a new line by pressing enter. Am I using the wrong commands? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for %%a in ("dirname 1" "dirname2" "as many as you want") do rd /s /q "%%~a"
```

should do what you want - %%a is set to each [optionally-quoted] argument in turn. You **Must** use the quotes if the directoryname contains separators like spaces.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use a `for` loop to iterate over a list of directories, as per:

```
pax> for %d in (c:\dir1 c:\other\dir2) do echo %d
c:\dir1
c:\other\dir2
```

In your particular case, it would be something akin to (in a cmd file):

```
for %%d in (c:\dir1 c:\other\dir2) do rmdir "%%~d" /s /q
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, this worked as well. I'll archive this method as an alternative for future use. I would like to accept both answers, but can only accept one...

Answer (score 2):

You can find subdirectories by name automaticly and delete them

```
for /f %%d in ('dir /b "C:\exampledir\searched_dir_name*"') do rd  /s /q "C:\exampledir\%%d"
```

this command will delete all directories with name "searched_dir_name" in directory C:\exampledir\